# Preferred connection pool settings on slow DB server

Tags: spring, jsf, c3p0

In a JSF2+Spring web application, I'm using c3p0 for connection pooling. The DB server seems to be quite slow on establishing new connections, after a restart of the container (tomcat7, no persistence across restarts) quite often requests run into timeouts in `awaitAvailable`.

However, the DB server's owner isn't able to tweak the server itself, so I need to tweak the connection pool settings.

Any recommendations on this? Which values should I touch?

(DB is Oracle 11, actual pool settings are: `checkoutTimeout = 10000`, `maxPoolSize = 110`, `idleConnectionTestPeriod = 300`, `minPoolSize = 5`)

Comment: one easy suggestion is to set a large acquireIncrement, so that c3p0 prefetches a bunch of new Connections when it begins to experience load.

Comment: which specific value would you recommend, given the above pool parameters? I expect about 5-15 simultaneous users on this application; in the average case a user sends about 10 HTTP-requests (triggering DB queries) to get through the desired workflow.

Comment: it's an art, not a science (and not a precise art, lots of values will work reasonably well). Given the size of your pool (maxPoolSize) and the usage you describe, acquireIncrement of 10-15 might be good. if you really need to minimize app footprint in terms of number of open Connections, you can go smaller, but i'd start big (eg 15) and verify that it resolves the problem you are seeing, then fine-tune down as desired.

Comment: Setting acquireIncrement to 10 solved this issue for me. If you're keen on reputation, please post your suggestion as answer - I'll check it as correct answer :-)